# SQL count all nulls in every columns in all tables in a sys tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL:

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Schema NVARCHAR(100) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Nulls') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Nulls

CREATE TABLE #Nulls (TableName sysname, ColumnName sysname, ColumnPosition int 
, NullCount int , NonNullCount int)

SELECT @sql += 'SELECT  '''+TABLE_NAME+''' AS TableName ,      

'''+COLUMN_NAME+''' AS ColumnName,  '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),ORDINAL_POSITION)+'''AS ColumnPosition,     
SUM(CASE WHEN '+COLUMN_NAME+' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CountNulls ,   
COUNT(' +COLUMN_NAME+') CountnonNulls FROM   
'+QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)+';'+ CHAR(10)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema AND (@Table IS NULL OR TABLE_NAME = @Table)

INSERT INTO #Nulls 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

SELECT * 
FROM #Nulls
```

This goes through counting all nulls the way i expect it. However, I want to use this sql to loop over each tables in a catalogue for example in the

```
  information.schema.table
```

Can someone please provide the sql required to do this, I am completely clueless with using cursors.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a cursor. Just set your `@Table` to `NULL`

`DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(100) = NULL`

Then change your `WHERE` clause from this

`WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema AND TABLE_NAME = @Table`

to `WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema AND (@Table IS NULL OR TABLE_NAME = @Table)`

So the entire code...

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Schema NVARCHAR(100) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Nulls') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Nulls

CREATE TABLE #Nulls (TableName sysname, ColumnName sysname, ColumnPosition int 
, NullCount int , NonNullCount int)

SELECT @sql += 'SELECT  '''+TABLE_NAME+''' AS TableName ,      

'''+COLUMN_NAME+''' AS ColumnName,  '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),ORDINAL_POSITION)+'''AS ColumnPosition,     
SUM(CASE WHEN '+COLUMN_NAME+' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CountNulls ,   
COUNT(' +COLUMN_NAME+') CountnonNulls FROM   
'+QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)+';'+ CHAR(10)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema AND (@Table IS NULL OR TABLE_NAME = @Table)

INSERT INTO #Nulls 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

SELECT * 
FROM #Nulls
```

Comment: `AND COALESCE(@Table,TABLE_NAME) = TABLE_NAME` or `AND NULLIF(@Table,TABLE_NAME) = TABLE_NAME`

Comment: I am getting the error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 406
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Column'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 412
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Column'.

Comment: @abs786123 what else did you change?

Comment: use quotename() in your code generating query, e.g.: quotename(column_name)

Comment: I have made the changes but still get the error, I have posted the new SQL , if you can please look above

Comment: @abs786123 did you run what I posted? And i run your code without error... so it must be somewhere else in your query window.

Comment: @abs786123 -- the code above did not move the trailing `;`  and it has two FROM statements -- just totally wrong.

Comment: @scsimon, yes thats what i copied and this is the error i got: I am getting the error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 406 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Column'. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 412 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Column'

Comment: The original query i posted worked, so its somewhere in the changes you made?

Comment: it probably has to do with your column names... try changing the `@sql` to `@sql += 'select TableName = ''' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + quotename(table_name) + ''' , ColumnName = ''' + quotename(column_name) + ''' , ColumnPosition = ''' + convert(varchar(5) , ordinal_position) + ''' , CountNulls = sum(case when ' + quotename(column_name) + ' is null then 1 else 0 end) , CountnonNulls = count(' + quotename(column_name) + ') from ' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + quotename(table_name) + ';' + char(10)`

Comment: But i don't get what you did to make it work? what was it?

Comment: some of your columns probably have spaces or some other character that requires square brackets: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/do-not-use-spaces-or-other-invalid-chara/