# t-sql select column names from all tables where there is at least 1 null value

Tags: t-sql

Context: I am exploring a new database (in MS SQL server), and I want to know for each table, all columns that have null values.

I.e. result would look something like this:

```
table column nulls
Tbl1  Col1   8
```

I have found this code here on stackoverflow, that makes a table of table-columnnames - without the WHERE statement which is my addition. 
I tried to filter for nulls in WHERE statement, but then the table ends up empty, and I see why - i am checking if the col name is actually null, and not its contents. But can't figure out how to proceed.

```
select schema_name(tab.schema_id) as schema_name,
tab.name as table_name, 
col.name as column_name

from sys.tables as tab
     inner join sys.columns as col
         on tab.object_id = col.object_id
     left join sys.types as t
         on col.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
-- in this where statement, I am trying to filter for nulls, but i get an empty result. and i know there are nulls
where col.name is null
order by schema_name, table_name, column_id
```

I also tried this (see 4th line):

```
select schema_name(tab.schema_id) as schema_name,
tab.name as table_name, 
col.name as column_name
,(select count(*) from tab.name where col.name is null) as countnulls

from sys.tables as tab
     inner join sys.columns as col
         on tab.object_id = col.object_id
     left join sys.types as t
         on col.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
order by schema_name, table_name, column_id
```

the last one returns an error "Invalid object name 'tab.name'."

Comment: col.name is the name of the column in the table and I don't think it can be NULL.

Comment: @winniep, I added another thing i tried.  it seems that col.name is an object of name, but i don't know how to reference it as a colname. I.e. if i was querying 1 table, I would say select * from Sometable where Somecolumn is null. This works, but using col.name like that does not work.

Comment: After the `from`, there needs to be a table name, not a variable that includes it. You have to use dynamic sql for that.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, I don't know how to do that :(   also, i need to list all columns in all tables where there is a null value. if i use a static name of the table, and i still don't know how to change that, this would just give me 1 table. And I need all of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL count all nulls in every columns in all tables in a sys tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850949/sql-count-all-nulls-in-every-columns-in-all-tables-in-a-sys-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**column name can't be null** but if you mean nullable column (column that accept null value) that has null value at least so you can use following statement:

```
declare @schema varchar(255), @table varchar(255),  @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)

DECLARE getinfo cursor for
SELECT schema_name(tab.schema_id) as schema_name,tab.name , col.name from sys.tables as tab
     inner join sys.columns as col on tab.object_id = col.object_id
where col.is_nullable =1 
order by schema_name(tab.schema_id),tab.name,col.name

OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @schema,@table,@col

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    set @schema  = QUOTENAME(@schema)
    set @table = QUOTENAME(@table)
    set @col =  QUOTENAME(@col)
    SELECT @cmd = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM '+ @schema +'.'+ @table +' WHERE ' + @col + ' IS NULL) BEGIN SELECT '''+@schema+''' as schemaName, '''+@table+''' as tablename, '''+@col+''' as columnName, * FROM '+ @schema +'.'+ @table +' WHERE ' + @col + ' IS NULL end'
    EXEC(@cmd)

    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into  @schema,@table,@col
END

CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo
```

that use cursor on all `nullable columns` in every `table` in the Database then check if this column has at least one null value if yes will select **schema Name, table name, column name and all records that has null value** in this column

but if you want to get only count of nulls you can use the following statement:

```
declare @schema varchar(255), @table varchar(255),  @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)

DECLARE getinfo cursor for
SELECT schema_name(tab.schema_id) as schema_name,tab.name , col.name from sys.tables as tab
     inner join sys.columns as col on tab.object_id = col.object_id
where col.is_nullable =1 
order by schema_name(tab.schema_id),tab.name,col.name

OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @schema,@table,@col

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set @schema  = QUOTENAME(@schema)
    set @table = QUOTENAME(@table)
    set @col =  QUOTENAME(@col)
    SELECT @cmd = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM '+ @schema +'.'+ @table +' WHERE ' + @col + ' IS NULL) BEGIN SELECT '''+@schema+''' as schemaName, '''+@table+''' as tablename, '''+@col+''' as columnName, count(*) as nulls FROM '+ @schema +'.'+ @table +' WHERE ' + @col + ' IS NULL end'
    EXEC(@cmd)

    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into  @schema,@table,@col
END
```

that use cursor on all `nullable columns` in every `table` in the Database then check if this column has at least one null value if yes will select **schema Name, table name, column name and count all records that has null value** in this column

Comment: hi, Ahmed. I need to check where there are nulls. If a column is nullable in error, I need to see where the values were skipped and need to be filled in. so basically, I need a list of table with columns and count of null. I will amend my question to include the desired output.

Comment: if a column in any table has null value it means that the column is nullable column so you can use this statement to get these columns then you can check it table by table

Comment: Ahmed, I can do table by table without checking whether it is nullable. It takes long time. I am trying to arrive at the code that gives me a summary of all columns with nulls. Is it possible or am i trying achieve unachievable?

Comment: @LanaB check the updated solution it will print table and column that has at least one null value

Comment: Ahmed, thank you for trying.  However, it returned me 3 lines, table: sysdiagrams column: version
table: sysdiagrams column: definition
table: CustomerDemographics column: CustomerDesc.   There are many more, i.e. I know that Region in Customers table has nulls - and it's not returned.

Comment: @LanaB are you sure your are using you DB not master DB

Comment: what is your DB name

Comment: it is MS SQL server express edition, and I have USE MyDatabase clause, so definitely it's running on the db i need

Comment: @LanaB could you try updated solution I make it get the table name, column and the whole record that has null values

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, this is not a concise table i wanted originally, but it's actually better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LanaB welcome, check updated solution I have added schema name and count of null if you want to get count only

Comment: Why do you have `top 1` (without an `order by` clause) in an `exists` query? Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: @HABO regarding with top 1 or without top 1 it will be the same result and execution plan, on the other hand odd names like [New Table] or [From] i have surrounded it with squire brackets so it won't make any issue.

Comment: As shown in the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) `QuoteName` will change `'abc[]def'` to `'[abc[]]def]'`. Not quite the same as throwing a pair of squire _[sic]_ brackets around any input. And adding code that does nothing, e.g. `top 1`, doesn't improve the answer.

Comment: @HABO thanks for you notes, solution have been updated according to your notes