# SQL: Is there a way to count Null records from Information Schema in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I currently have a script that pulls all the table names, columns and data types. I am trying to add a column that would count the number of null records for each column.

I've tried to add this into the script however I am not getting it to work.

Current Script:

select distinct table_name, column_name, data_type
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'schema'

Is there something I can add in similar to the below?

1. sum(case when column is null then 1 else 0 end)
2. select count(column) where column is not null

Answer (score 0):

Since count() only counts non-null values we can calculate the number of non-null entries in a column easily.  Subtract from the total number of rows and you have number of null entries.

```
select count(*) - count(column) as num_null_in_column;
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. This makes sense but I still am not able to get this to work within my script

Comment: So what is your script running on and written in?  Is the issue errors or wrong results? Can you provide the SQL that you are issuing that is errorring or producing wrong results?

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for getting back to me. My script is running on amazon redshift. I am currently running the below script to provide me all the tables and column names in the schema.  the results have the column names in each row. I am hoping to then see how many nulls are in each of those columns.  The end result would be something like row 1: Table 1, column name 1, 0 nulls Row 2 Table 1, column name 2, 5 nulls... select  distinct table_name, column_name, data_type 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'schema'

Comment: I think this thread is what I am trying to do but I am unable to adjust it to work with my tables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850949/sql-count-all-nulls-in-every-columns-in-all-tables-in-a-sys-tables

Comment: I think I see what you are looking for now - you want the "script" to be in Redshift. So you can get your first 2 columns from SVV_COLUMNS, correct? You want the "script" to be flexible and adjust to the number of tables and columns the database has as things change over time, correct?  This can be done AFAIK with a stored procedure that takes schema, table, and column and returns the difference described in the answer. An alternative approach would be to have an external tool loop through SVV_COLUMNS and put the results in a summary table which you likely want anyway. Cont.

Comment: The upside of the stored procedure is that everyone can run the query any regenerate the results whenever they like but since this is scanning all data in your cluster this may not be the best idea.  The external approach has the upside of leveraging the power of the AWS ecosystem to provide the "smarts" while leaving Redshift to do what it is good at - processing data.  I personally lean toward the "external" approach because it gives "operational / orchestrational" duties to tools made for these jobs and expands the data solution to utilize the entire suite of AWS tools.

Comment: Thanks, Bill - This is very helpful and I think you nailed my overall goal. I think the external solution would probably better especially to scale something like this but I, unfortunately, am brand new to SQL (if you couldnt tell already by my terminology). Do you think you could point me in the right direction for the stored procedure approach?  Also the amount of data isnt that large so I think it will be ok.

Comment: I'd start at - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html  There are some examples and a reference.  Just note that there are BEGIN and LOOP sections.